# how to find$ (g\circ f)(x)$ if $f(x)=|8x|$ and $g(x)=-6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $f(x)=|8x|$ and $g(x)=-6$

find $(g\circ f)(x)$
I'm not sure how to complete this question and similar questions to it.

I can do the first part: 
$(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) =g(|8x|)$

I can't figure out the second part, because there is no $x$ in $g(x)$ that I can substitute $|8x|$ into.

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? As it stands $(g\circ f)(x) = -6 $ for all $x$.

Comment: `g(x) = −6` If $\,g\,$ is a constant function, then so is $\,g \circ f\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You substitute into all $x$s. If there are none, you're done, because you've substituted into all zero of the $x$s:
$$  (g \circ f)(x)
\\  g(f(x))
\\  g(\lvert 8x \rvert)
\\  -6
$$